# Waiting on a call-back

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, background-check, job-acceptance

So I recently applied at Target and already completed my interview. Immediately after my interview they offered a job to me contingent on my passing of a drug test. I took the drug test the next day within the time limit at the clinic they partner with and got an email 4 days later regarding an orientation. I was told during my interview to disregard the email as it would be automated and the information in the email would be incorrect. I contacted them after receiving the email just to make sure I should disregard it and I was again told to ignore it and wait for call from them during the week (I called on a Sunday) about my orientation. It has been 8 days since I made that call to them about the email and I have heard nothing back.

My concern comes from the possibility of failing the drug test. It is more than likely that I would have passed it, but there was still the chance of failure. I have been told that failing a drug test would result in a call from the clinic and no call back from Target. Is that information true? It's been almost 2 weeks since the test and they told me they would have test results within a week of the test date. I haven't heard anything from the clinic. Is it more likely that I am being impatient and paranoid or that I failed the test and subsequently never got a phone call about an orientation?

Comment: I have been contacted when failing a test. If it has been a week beyond when they should get the results, I would reach out to them and find out for sure.

Comment: @targetguy23 - Can you post back with how this ended for you?

Answer (score 7):

It seems strange to me that if you failed the dug test, they wouldn't even call you to tell you that you failed.  Since the amount of time they told you to wait has passed, I would reach out to them.  Don't ask whether you passed or failed, or allude to the possibility that you could have failed, just state that the time has passed and you're checking on the status of your application.

Comment: Spot on. Exactly what I'd do. Should have read this answer before commenting

Comment: I'd like to add that you should follow up at the latest every 7 days. I personally call back every 4 days. They are looking to hire someone, why is it taking them 7 days to let you know yes/no?

Comment: Thank you! I took your advice and called with "concerns about the status of my orientation date". Turns out they were just waiting on a couple other applicants from other stores in the area before setting up the orientation. I was told to expect a call about it by the end of the week.

Comment: Congrats!  Sounds like potentially good news!

Comment: @TheMuffinMan you might want to read http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p.  Calling every 4 days can get you labelled as a pest or high maintenance.  There are lots of answers that explain why it can take more than 7 days too.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Thanks for the link. I suppose in the field of software development if it takes 7 days to get back to someone it's likely they already found another position.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, I am in the field of software dev and if someone called me every 4 days, I would label him an annoyance. It takes what it takes and these calls don't speed things up.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently had the same issue and have not been notified within a week like they told me. I've waited the week this makes week 2 still no call I even called them i recieved no answer. I decided to just be patient and wait like you said they probably is waiting on others to get settled in before calling me for my training as well.